# Is my code, parallelized with OpenMP, so slow because of concurrent memory access?

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, openmp, cpu, hardware

I have some code in which the contents of one (typically big) array is added to that of another array of the same size:

```cpp
for (long i = 0; i < len; i++)
     data1[i] += data2[i];
```

It looks like this should be easily parallelizable using OpenMP:

```cpp
#pragma omp parallel for
for (long i = 0; i < len; i++)
     data1[i] += data2[i];
```

However, even though I have 8 cores + 8 hyperthreads, the speedup is minimal (maybe 10%). I tried to finetune this a bit:

```cpp
#pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic, 1000)
```

...but without effect. I see that all cores and hyperthreads are working concurrently, but only at 10 or 15%.

Other functionality, e.g. to find the minimum (so that you only have to read, not write, to memory) in an array easily runs 5 times faster with parallelization.

This led me to the hypothesis that maybe the parallelization doesn't help much because writing memory is slow and cannot be done concurrently by different cores. Does that make sense? I have pretty old hardware: an HP Z600 workstation (2010) with two [Xeon E5540](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/37104/intel-xeon-processor-e5540-8m-cache-2-53-ghz-5-86-gts-intel-qpi.html) CPU's, of 4 cores + 4 hyperthreads each, and with 8 MB cache. The memory is DDR3 at 1066 MHz.

My questions:

- Do you think this is indeed the reason that the parallelization doesn't do much?
- Is there anything I can do to benefit more from parallelization?

Comment: You should use a profiler to find out where the bottlenecks are and optimize accordingly.

Comment: Your reason does makes sense especially for such an old system even with 2 separate CPUs. This operation is very much limited by the memory bandwidth.

Comment: `dynamic` schedule can lead to cache line bouncing (different threads processing different parts of the array in repeated calls compared to `static`. This can also be affected by the way you [initialize the array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72055210/openmp-array-initialization-impact/72055520). Overall I think it would make sense for you to measure your memory bandwidth and compare it to the theoretical values and measured performance. Also, if repeated calls on smaller arraysr that fit into the cache are faster, that would be another good indicator

Comment: Generally, I would use an OS-specific  or C++ std::thread based threadpool instead of OpenMP.

Comment: You're probably getting murdered by false sharing.  Scott Meyers did an excellent talk that covers this near the start: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WDIkqP4JbkE

Comment: @StephenNewell False sharing is definitely not a problem here

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis whatever threading system used, won't magically solve the memory bandwidth bottleneck issue.

Comment: You may want to check the `CHUNK` size. You want large ranges of the memory to be assigned to each thread; not individual locations. A thing you don't want cache pages/lines being swapped out, things you want is consecutive memory locations so they can be predicatively be prefetched before use into the cache.

Comment: @StephenNewell Great video, thanks! However, wouldn't the `schedule(dynamic, 1000)`, which if I understand correctly instructs each thread to process 1000 consecutive iterations, avoid the false sharing?

Comment: @MartinYork When unspecified, the static chunk size is (number of iterations)/(number of threads).

Comment: @doetoe Unless you have pretty small `len` (but I assume it is large, as you mention a "big array"... that said specifying which len you are testing would be nice), false sharing is **not** a problem here. A cache line is typically 128 bytes, that means 16 double elements: you would start having observable false sharing effects for chunks about that size.

Comment: @PierU I agree that false sharing is not the issue here but just for correctness: I'm pretty sure no current x86 CPU has 128 byte cache line size. It's 64. If you know an example, please correct me on this. However, there is also this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72126606/should-the-cache-padding-size-of-x86-64-be-128-bytes

Comment: @doetoe - I don't know OpenMP, but a 10% boost with how many threads you're throwing at this screams you're hitting a bottleneck somewhere.  Compare your current performance with 2 threads and 4 threads, and run everything through a profiler.

Comment: One thing that hasn't been touched upon is that you run a NUMA system. That means it is even more important to keep memory use local to the CPU for which it was allocated by the OS. On linux that is whatever CPU  first touched the memory page. On Windows it's the one that did the allocation (AFAIK). NUMA also increases the cost of thread synchronization and therefore the overhead of each OpenMP construct.

Comment: @Homer512 I was indeed unsure for the actual cache line sizes.

Answer (score 4):

Your hypothesis is mostly correct, and your calculations are typically "memory bound", that is, there are too few calculations compared to the amount the data that is transfered from/to the memory and the bottleneck is the transfer rate between the CPU and the memory. Thus, using more core doesn't help.

On a more recent CPU (particularly on the ones that are designed for servers) you may possibly observe a higher speed-up, because in the recent years the memory bandwidth has increasing faster than the monocore performances.

**Edit**: note that in case obvious memory bound calculations, the best performances are not always obtained with the maximum possible number of threads, as they are all competing for accessing the memory. Using 2 or 4 threads may possibly be (a bit) faster than using 8 threads.

**Edit 2**: for a more complete answer I am gathering the other possible effects that have been mentioned in the comments (@Homer512) and in the answer by @JerryCoffin:

- NUMA effects because you have 2 CPUs (slower memory access when one CPU tries accessing the memory that is attached to the other CPU)
- Thread creation overheads (visible if your arrays are not large enough)
- (not already mentioned) "cold start" effects (when the CPU is idle the motherborad may lower the frequency, and it can take a bit of time to get back to the base frequency, so that the first calculations are slower)

All the above effects partly depend on the way you have written your test code. That's why it's important to show the whole code and not only a small piece. Also:

- Turbo frequency effect: when a single core is used, the CPU most of time operates at the Turbo frequency, while it's more likely operating at the base frequency when all the cores are used. On your CPUs, the Turbo frequencies would give a ~10% performance bonus to the single core execution.

Comment: Server CPUs, especially modern Xeons, have much worse single-thread / per-thread memory bandwidth, as well as more total bandwidth from more memory controllers, so you need multiple cores to saturate them.  "Client" CPUs like a typical modern 8-core can still come pretty close to maxing out their memory bandwidth with one core. I don't know how much this has changed with DRAM speeds more than doubling since Skylake, but see [Why is Skylake so much better than Broadwell-E for single-threaded memory throughput?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39260020)

Comment: The OP's dual-socket Xeon E5540 is ancient, Nehalem generation, long before Skylake-generation Xeons ("Xeon Scalable") switched from a ring to a mesh interconnect.  In fact Nehalem Xeon might just be a shared bus instead of the ring interconnect that was new in Sandybridge (https://chipsandcheese.com/2023/08/04/sandy-bridge-setting-intels-modern-foundation/ has a graph of multithreaded memory bandwidth vs. working set size, for Westmere Xeon X5650 vs. Sandybridge Xeon E5-1650 and has some block diagrams of internals).

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how you've written your code, it's pretty easy to get tripped up by the time taken to create threads to run the code. For example, consider this code that expands your fragment out to a complete program, and runs the code over vectors of various sizes:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <algorithm>
#include <chrono>
#include <numeric>
#include <locale>
#include <omp.h>
#include <iomanip>

template <class Container>
void init(Container &data1, Container &data2) {
    srand(1);
    std::generate(data1.begin(), data1.end(), rand);
    std::generate(data2.begin(), data2.end(), rand);
}

int main() { 
    std::cout.imbue(std::locale(""));
    using namespace std::chrono;

    for (unsigned size = 250'000; size < 50'000'000; size *= 2) {
        std::vector<uint64_t> data1(size);
        std::vector<uint64_t> data2(size);

        init(data1, data2);        

        auto start = high_resolution_clock::now();
        for (int i=0; i<size; i++)
            data1[i] += data2[i];

        auto stop = high_resolution_clock::now();

        auto sum = std::accumulate(data1.begin(), data1.end(), 0ULL);
        init(data1, data2);

        auto start2 = high_resolution_clock::now();
        #pragma omp parallel for
        for (int i=0; i<size; i++)
            data1[i] += data2[i];
        auto stop2 = high_resolution_clock::now();

        auto sum2 = std::accumulate(data1.begin(), data1.end(), 0ULL);

        std::cout << "size: " << size << "\n";
        std::cout << "\tsum 1: " << sum << "\n";
        std::cout << "\tsum 2: " << sum2 << "\n";

        auto dur1 = duration_cast<microseconds>(stop - start).count();
        auto dur2 = duration_cast<microseconds>(stop2 - start2).count();

        std::cout << "\t  no OMP: " << std::setw(10) << dur1 << "us\n";
        std::cout << "\twith OMP: " << std::setw(10) << dur2 << "us\n";
        std::cout << "\tSpeedup: " << (double)dur1 / dur2 << "\n"; 
    }
}
```

When I run this, I get results like this:

```
size: 250,000
    sum 1: 537,095,867,682,884
    sum 2: 537,095,867,682,884
      no OMP:        275us
    with OMP:      1,261us
    Speedup: 0.218081
size: 500,000
    sum 1: 1,073,756,018,481,283
    sum 2: 1,073,756,018,481,283
      no OMP:        479us
    with OMP:        172us
    Speedup: 2.78488
size: 1,000,000
    sum 1: 2,147,344,996,944,184
    sum 2: 2,147,344,996,944,184
      no OMP:        655us
    with OMP:        224us
    Speedup: 2.92411
size: 2,000,000
    sum 1: 4,294,715,742,631,183
    sum 2: 4,294,715,742,631,183
      no OMP:      2,230us
    with OMP:        496us
    Speedup: 4.49597
size: 4,000,000
    sum 1: 8,590,750,767,966,991
    sum 2: 8,590,750,767,966,991
      no OMP:      6,303us
    with OMP:      2,135us
    Speedup: 2.95222
size: 8,000,000
    sum 1: 17,180,424,628,343,770
    sum 2: 17,180,424,628,343,770
      no OMP:     12,336us
    with OMP:      4,061us
    Speedup: 3.03768
size: 16,000,000
    sum 1: 34,358,679,947,677,733
    sum 2: 34,358,679,947,677,733
      no OMP:     23,917us
    with OMP:      7,805us
    Speedup: 3.06432
size: 32,000,000
    sum 1: 68,722,612,973,387,093
    sum 2: 68,722,612,973,387,093
      no OMP:     47,524us
    with OMP:     15,447us
    Speedup: 3.07658
```

Almost regardless of the starting size I set, in the first run the OpenMP code is quite slow, but the subsequent runs are much faster.

Although it's difficult to be 100% certain, I'd guess this is (at least largely) the time to create the thread pool to run the code in parallel. Once that's complete, subsequent runs using OpenMP show something closer to the results you'd hope for: the OpenMP version is usually around 3 times as fast as without.

Disclaimer: of course, the CPU I'm using is different from yours (an E5-2680 V4), and that means its memory is different as well (DDR4 vs. DDR3). So, it's possible that on your machine, even using identical code, your results won't follow the same pattern. I certainly would *not* expect it to have exactly the same ratios, but I'd guess with a large enough array you'll get more than a 10% improvement from OpenMP. Based on Peter Cordes' comments, it might turn out to be about the same level of improvement though (and there are few people who know the details of x86 microarchitecture nearly as well as Peter does--and most of those few work for Intel/AMD, and can't talk to us mere mortals about it).

Comment: Good point. Nonetheless I assume that if you were starting with a a very large size, the thread creation overhead (seems like 1ms) would not be noticeable (with a size=32M, the total time is 15.5ms, and it would be 16.5ms, still much faster than without OMP)

Comment: @PierU: yes, if it's large enough, you can save enough otherwise to cover up the thread creation time (but different people's ideas of "very large" can vary over a pretty wide range too).

Comment: E5-2680 (https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/64583/intel-xeon-processor-e5-2680-20m-cache-2-70-ghz-8-00-gt-s-intel-qpi.html) is a Sandybridge-EP from 2012 which uses DDR3-1600.  Did you actually mean E5-2680 v3 or v4 (Haswell or Broadwell) that use DDR4?  Those also have AVX2 for 32-byte integer vectors, although even 16-byte vectors should pretty much saturate L2 bandwidth, especially before Skylake boosted L2 <-> L1 bandwidth (and seriously worsened per-core / single-core L3 bandwidth in Xeon Scalable processors, although later generations aren't as bad.)

Comment: Anyway, your E5-2680 (v1 or v4) uses a ring bus and has great aggregate bandwidth; your benchmarks show single-thread bandwidth is 3x lower.  Apparently Nehalem/Westmere Xeon (like the OP's) also needs multiple threads to max out the memory controllers; https://chipsandcheese.com/2023/08/04/sandy-bridge-setting-intels-modern-foundation/ compares SnB against the previous generation.  From the graphs of 1T mem B/W and all-core mem B/W, we see Westmere at 20.41 GB/sec all-core, and just over 4 bytes / cycle (read-only) with a single core.  Assuming it was at 3.06GHz turbo, that's ~12.3 GB/s.

Comment: So the OP might expect a speedup of about 1.66x from OpenMP for large-enough arrays to amortize thread overhead.  (Unless they're so large that TLB misses are a bottleneck...)  Or 3.3x on the OP's 2-socket system if NUMA placement of their array is *perfect*, so each OpenMP thread is working on local DRAM.  That probably only happens if they first touch those pages inside OpenMP loops that got scheduled the same way.  (I'm guessing chipsandcheese tested single-socket systems, so their single vs. all ratio is for the memory controllers on one chip.)

Comment: @PeterCordes: Oops--yeah, I accidentally left out the "V4" part.